# Extra parentheses near arrow operator

Tags: c, pointers, parentheses

A program that I'm trying to decode includes the following line:

```
#define nn(sp)   ((sp)->nn)
```

From the context (not shown), I'm pretty sure that 'sp' is a pointer to a struct which contains 'nn' as one of its variables.

In the expression "((sp)->nn)", does the inner set of parentheses serve any conceivable purpose?  If not, might the outer set of parentheses also serve no purpose?

Comment: Think order of operations...

Comment: Of course I look for potential operations when dealing with parentheses, but I don't see the relevance for the inner parens.  Specifically, what kind of 'operation' could be intrinsic to 'sp', such that 'sp' would need to be set off with parens?  I'm new to C!

Comment: `&var->nn` and `(&var)->nn`. The first is parsed as: `&(var->nn)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#define nn(sp)   ((sp)->nn)
```

The inner parentheses are required. If you pass a pointer like `p + 10` or `*p` to `nn` macro, you would get some troubles without the inner parentheses as `->` has higher precedence than `+` and unary `*`.

The outer parentheses are not required here as the expression involves a postfix operation and no operator has greater precedence than postfix operators.

Answer (score 4):

It's a general defensive strategy to wrap macro arguments and the entire substituted text in parens. This protects the macro from unintended precendence changes.

Consider if the `sp` argument is a dereferenced pointer.

```
nn(*x)  //--> ((*x)->nn)
```

But without the inner parens:

```
nn(*x)  //--> (*x->nn)
```